# How to fetch data from grid and pass to the textbox field

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I'm doing this sample, anyone has an idea how to fetch all the data from the kendo grid and pass all the data into the textbox field under the grid when button submit is click?

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/AHOkegiZ)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I already add a function when each row is selected, all the data for its row display an alert message. But, I want to fetch all the data from the grid, not from each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can explore grid object by invoking console.log(grid) on button onClick event:

`<button ..... onClick="console.log(grid)">Submit</button>`

If you're using Chrome, you can open a Developer Console to view what grid object contains
[image]

Now that you know you can access those data from the Kendo grid, you can do:

```js
const fetchGridData = () => {
  let data = []
  grid._data.forEach(row => data = data.concat([row.ageGroup,row.basePax,row.extraBed]))
  document.getElementById('allData').value = data.join(",")
}
```

And don't forget to call `fetchGridData()` on button onClick event
`<button ..... onClick="fetchGridData()">Submit</button>`